# Why 4‐methylidenespiro[2.4]heptane cannot be converted to 1‐chlorobicyclo[3.2.0]heptane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halogenation

According to the solution, the following reaction is not correct:

> [image: 4‐methylidenespiro[2.4]heptane + HCl → 1‐chlorobicyclo[3.2.0]heptane]

But why? I have tried solving in the following steps:

1. Forming a carbocation by breaking the double bond.
2. Expanding the ring.
3. Adding a $\ce{Cl-}$ anion.

This should thereby form the compound that is shown. But the solution is given that this reaction is not correct. Can you please explain to me why?

Comment: Count the carbons!

Comment: It has lost a methyl group.

Comment: Yes got it... sorry for such a silly question

Comment: @ManuShukla No need to apologize, I find the question to be fine. Plus you added your thought process which is always a good thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

Here the concept of angular strain comes into the picture. The ideal tetrahedral and is around 109° 29'. As the angle between the C−C bond increases, it is more away from the ideal $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridization and hence will become more unstable.

For a cyclohexane molecule, the angle between the C−C bonds is 120°, therefore the deviation from the ideal angle is 10° 31', whereas for a cyclopentane the angle between C−C bonds is 108°, therefore the deviation from the ideal tetrahedral angle is around 1.5°. This is a very low deviation.

Since the transition is from cyclopentane which has a relatively lower deviation from the ideal angle to cyclohexane which has a relatively higher deviation from the ideal angle, the above transition does not take place.

Plus the number of carbons are not balanced in your reaction.

Comment: Only your last line is relevant. (1) There's no cyclohexane in the question(!!). (2) Angle strain is only one part of a strain in a molecule. (3) The difference in angle strain is not as large as you think it is; certainly not enough to prevent a cyclopentane -> cyclohexane ring expansion from occurring. These types of reactions occur all the time. Although it feels kind of moot discussing this in detail here given point (1).

Comment: what i ment was that the angel strain for the cyclopentane is lesser than that of cyclohexane and hence the transition between to cyclohexane from cyclopentane does not take place